# How do i use play ws library in normal sbt project instead of play?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

*When i tried using Play WS library in a normal sbt project instead of play project I was bound to use play.api.Play.current and got* **java.lang.RuntimeException: "There is no started application"** *when tried to run the application.*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Usage in 2.4.x

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient   

val wsClient = NingWSClient()
wsClient.url("http://wwww.something.com").get()
```

build.sbt :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.4.3"
```

### Usage in 2.5.x

```
import play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
wsClient.url("http://wwww.something.com").get()

//at the very end, to shutdown stuff cleanly :
wsClient.close()
actorSystem.terminate()
```

build.sbt :

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.5.4"
```

### Logs

As someone noted in the comment, by default you might get a bunch of verbose logs coming from the underlying async-http-client. One way to fix it is to start configuring a *logback.xml*, and placing it in *src/main/resources*

```
<configuration>

<conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <!-- The logging pattern, you might want to adapt it -->
        <pattern>%d %coloredLevel %t - %logger - %message%n%xException</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Here you can change the levels of specific loggers -->
<logger name="somelogger" level="INFO" />

<!-- Default logging level for every logger -->
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. posting a link to a very useful comparison of HTTP toolkits for Scala: https://www.implicitdef.com/2015/11/19/comparing-scala-http-client-libraries.html

Comment: seems deprecated already. they recommended now:play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClient

Comment: I thought I used to be able to do this in `sbt console` but I keep seeing: `res23: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse] = List()` as the return from `get`.., !

Comment: ^^^ try using `Await.result(),` `List()` means that there is no value yet

Answer (score 17):

To use play-ws outside of play see "Using WSClient" section of documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaWS

```
val builder = new com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
val client = new play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSClient(builder.build())
val response = client.url(url).get()
```

Comment: What is the dependency-line needed for one's `build.sbt`/`build.scala` file? Is a special resolver necessary?

Comment: try (untested): `resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"` and `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ws" % "2.3.7"`. (small note: play-ws has a dependency to play so you will have the whole play framwork in your project)

Comment: Does anyone know how to turn off WS's verbose logging (printing of all the response headers) in this scenario (i.e. using it outside of play). It makes it very hard to debug anything